# Is it possible to get the line number that threw an error?

Tags: ruby, exception

```
begin
  . . .
  # error occurs here
  . . .
rescue => error
  puts "Error: " + error.message
end
```

Is there a way to get the line number of *the statement where the error occurred*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just take the backtrace:

```
begin
  . . .
  # error occurs here
  . . .
rescue => error
  puts "Error: " + error.message
  puts error.backtrace
end
```

To get only the line number - just parse it out of the backtrace via a regex.

More information can be found here: [Catching line numbers in ruby exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119286/catching-line-numbers-in-ruby-exceptions)